# $f,g$ be two entire functions satisfies $|f^2(z)+g^2(z)|=1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$,

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be two entire functions satisfies $$|f^2(z)+g^2(z)|=1$$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, then

$1)$ $f(z)f'(z)+g(z)g'(z)=0$

$2)$ $f$ and $g$ must be constant

$3$ $f$ and $g$ are both bounded function

$4)$ $f$ and $g$ have no zero on the unit circle.

We know that $\sin^2(z)+\cos^2(z)=1$ so I can reject option $2,3$

How do I prove/disprove $1$ and $4$?

Comment: Use the chain rule for the first part.

Comment: I suppose $f^2(z)$ means $f(z)^2$?

Answer (score 4):

4) is obviously false since $f = 0$ and $g = 1$ do the job.

For 1) I think that it's useful to observe that $f(z)^2 + g(z)^2 = a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}$ implies $f(z) f'(z) + g(z) g'(z) = 0$. Now your condition implies that $f^2 + g^2$ is bounded and therefore constant by Liouville's theorem.